# How to pass a value from razor page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

How do you pass a value from razor into a C# class?

I want to pass the value from `autoCreateSoldPart` into the `soldPartSetting`, but I am not sure how to do that.

**Razor**

```
<p>
    @Html.Label("Auto recreate sold part", new { @for= "autoCreateSoldPart" })
    @{
        var lstSelect = new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "Yes", Value = "true" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "No", Value = "false" }
        };

        lstSelect.ForEach(o =>
        {
            if (o.Value == System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReCreateSoldPart"])
            {
                o.Selected = true;
            }
        });

        }
        @Html.DropDownList("autoCreateSoldPart", lstSelect, new { @class = "form-control" })
</p>
```

**Controller for razor**

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Settings()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = return View();
        }
    }
```

**C#**

```
public class PartBLL
{
    public static int AssignPartToShelf(string action, string userName, string itemNumber, string shelfNumber, string userToken)
    {
        if (soldPartSetting == true)
        {
            partService.ServiceInstance.UndoSoldItem(part.ID.Value, userToken);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: through a controller?!

Comment: check ViewBag item

Comment: Your view needs a form, and you submit that form to a controller method that accepts you model (which should have a property named `autoCreateSoldPart`). You really need to bu your self a good book, or at least work through the tutorials on the MVC site to learn the basics

Comment: I agree with Stephen, you don't do yourself a favor if you try to implement a quick and dirty solution. Pick a good tutorial and go through the basics, it will definitely pay off.